# Can not load logs Papertrail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, papertrail-app

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I want to show the rails logs on the service [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/). I do everything as indicated in the instruction:

```
sudo remote_syslog \ -p 34698 \ -d logs7.papertrailapp.com \ --pid-file=/var/run/remote_syslog.pid \ /home/admin/apps/project/backend/log/development.log
```

As a result, I have an error:

> 2018-08-28 04:09:26 CRITICAL  remote_syslog.go:240 Failed to start
>   server: No destination hostname specified

Comment: Have you set up you papertrail.yml file? https://github.com/papertrail/papertrail-cli/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Your command looks correct, but somehow the `-d` is not picked up. Maybe try with `--dest-host` or a configuration file https://github.com/papertrail/remote_syslog2/tree/v0.19#configuration instead.

Comment: Give us an update on this. ARe you using a .yml config file?